# JQuery- hotkeys and windows prompt issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, hotkeys, prompt

By referring to this [link](http://jshotkeys.googlepages.com/test-static-01.html)
I try to implement this powerful tool and facing some issue.

Every time when I click `Ctrl S`, it will popup a window prompt asking me whether I want to save my testing.html.

I want to ignore windows prompt.

What I want is simple:

1. when people click save button/ use shortcut key `ctrl s` from keyboard
2. script need to do a `Create()` checking
3. if true then continue to submit form, if false, then stop alert `Please enter question`, focus back to `txtQuestion`, and don't do any further action.

Below is the full source code for reference:
enter

```
   <html>
   <head>
       <style>
           * {font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial; font-size:0.95em}
           .eventNotifier{width: 100px; float: left; color:navy; 
                 border: dotted 1px navy; padding: 4px; background-color:white; 
                 margin:3px}
           .dirty{border: solid 1px #0ca2ff; color:white; 
                  background-color:#0ca2ff}
       </style>
   
       <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
       <script src="jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {

//weird- I found the alert Ctrl+S to appear twice.. ???
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
 if ((event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey)){
     alert("Ctrl+S pressed");
     event.preventDefault();
 }
});

               jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+s',
                      function(evt){ Create(); return false; });
               //jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+s',
                     //function (evt){jQuery('#_Ctrl_s'); return false; });
           });
       
           function Create()
           {
               var f = document.frm
       
               if (f.txtQuestion.value.length == 0)
               {
                   alert('Please enter Question.')
                   f.txtQuestion.focus()
                   return false
               }
               f.submit()
           }
   
       </script>
   </head>
   <body> 
       <form name="frm" method=post action="" >
         <div id="_Ctrl_s" class="eventNotifier">Ctrl+s</div>
         <input type=text name="txtQuestion" maxlength="255" 
                   class="field400" value="">
         <input type=button value="Save" name="BtnSave" onclick="Create()" 
                   class=text100>
       </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid showing the browser Save As dialog, you must prevent the default event action, example in plain jQuery:

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey)){
      alert("Ctrl+S pressed");
      event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: hmm.. funny thing is at the demo site, I can't see any .preventDefault() code, but it still running perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet is ok but in order to prevent default browser action (as showing Save dialog) you must catch the **KeyPress** event (not the KeyDown) and of course **return false**.

```
jQuery(document).bind('keypress', 'Ctrl+S',function (evt){ 
 //do job..
 return false
});
```

Comment: Note that this use requires the jQuery HotKeys plugin: https://github.com/ricardovaleriano/jquery.hotkeys